# How to prove False = 0<>0

Tags: coq

How can I prove

```
Goal False = (0<>0).
```

?

I tried `omega`, and I could not find any lemma that contains (False = *) or (* = False).

Comment: The issue requires the exact same answer you made, but I would not flag it as dup

Comment: Note that the proof of the bi-implication `False <-> (0<>0)` is easy to prove with `omega`.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I used to think that `<->` and `=` are interchangeable for `Prop` but apparently they are not, at least in 8.4

Comment: as Arthur explains in the other question, it never has been the case "in general". @KonstantinWeitz `intuition` is enough, no need to invoke the all-mighty omega here :D